# Image Processing: Fastest direct-neighbor pixel comparison

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I have a written a code, that takes the difference of intensities of neighbor pixels and gets the maximum difference. However I would like some thoughts on how to implement my "algorithm" faster. Till now I resorted to `switch`and `if`statements.

my code is simple yet messy. There is the thoughts behind it:

- go to my point of interest
- identify the pixels in its direct neighborhood
- calculate the difference of intensities
- compare the calculated intensities and deduce the maximum
- take the maximum to etc...

That lead me to multiple switch and if statements. Do you have any thoughts on that ?

Comment: I think you are essentially doing a morphological dilation, so try Googling algorithms for that.

Comment: exactly I am trying to do that but with morphological dilation you would add or subtract pixels according to the neighborhood criteria. My question is more specific, I am applying a certain algorithm to create skeletons. I want create branches from local maxima to local maximas all around the grid. Hence the comparison and deduction which pixel has more significance to become a saddle point

Answer (score 1):

You can see OpenCv library, not need write this code this library have this and many other function. Read this:

http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~bensapp/opencvdocs/ref/opencvref_cv.htm

Comment: could you be more precise ? I have not yet seen an algorithm that would look at neighboring pixels, get the differences in intensities and take them into consideration. If you could give a more precise answer, I would mark your answer as a solution. Thanks

Comment: please see in this site: www.it-ebooks.info and download this book: "OpenCV 2 Computer Vision Application Programming Cookbook" here show a recipe: "Scanning an image with neighbor access"

Comment: Thank you for the info, I will give you a vote up on that. However I just optimized neighbor access by utilizing pointers. The if and switch statements have to be for the time being the answer.